# React Routing issue Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

How to grab hash location with onload

```
            <Redirect exact from="/:id" to="/user/1231231"/>
            <Route path="/user/:id" exact component={UserComponent}/>
```

Comment: How about creating separate component for handling redirections and concatenating query params via `history.push`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what versions of packages you are using. But here basic example. Try to go `?profile=:id`

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-stackoverflow-lchu9

[gif](https://gfycat.com/familiarwanbeetle)

Comment: It gives me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined` I have updated my question with my packages thank you

Comment: There is no reason why it should not work, you need to debug. Also consider that I am using different version of router than you. Look to docs.